# How to Animate cards using HTML , CSS & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm diving into the world of CSS animation and attempting to replicate the card shuffling animation seen: https://go.topcreditcardfinder.com/

Here's a glimpse of what I've achieved so far:
https://youtu.be/GDIJ2K22cnY

I've managed to achieve the basic movement, but I'm struggling with improving the translation and relative movement for each card. My goal is to refine the animation for a smoother and more realistic card shuffling effect.
My cards are moving but the animation is sudden and is not creating a cyclic shuffle animation like what i am expecting. What I maybe doing wrong here?

Here's the code that I have written:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="./assets/Cart  Geometric  2.png" alt="Card 1">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="./assets/Cart  Geometric  5.png" alt="Card 2">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="./assets/Cart  Geometric  8.png" alt="Card 3">
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('./assets/Vector\ 1.png') center/cover no-repeat , linear-gradient(180deg, #DBE4ED 100%, #BABABA 100%)  ;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-container {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotateCard 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateCard {
    20% {
        transform: rotate(4deg) translateY(-10px);
        z-index: 3;
    }
    40%, 100% {
        transform: rotate(-4deg) translateY(10px);
        z-index: 2;
    }
    0%, 60%, 80% {
        transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

.card:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 2s; }
.card:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 4s; }

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 170px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the effect is that you're trying to achieve? That reference link shows cards that are simply translated to the left in a carousel fashion, but it sounds like you're trying to achieve a shuffling effect where the cards move over each other, which sounds completely different.

Comment: I am trying to achieve one like in the given link. I may have worded it wrong. apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated the animation at the link with just CSS here:

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: rotateCard 10.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateCard {
  /* Hold front */
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(1px);
  }
  /* Hold front */
  28.57% {
    transform: translateZ(1px);
  }
  /* Move left */
  33.33% {
    transform: rotate(-4deg) scale(0.9) translate(-15%, -5%);
  }
  /* Hold left */
  61.90% {
    transform: rotate(-4deg) scale(0.9) translate(-15%, -5%);
  }
  /* Move right */
  66.67% {
    transform: rotate(4deg) scale(0.9) translate(15%, -5%);
  }
  /* Hold right */
  95.23% {
    transform: rotate(4deg) scale(0.9) translate(15%, -5%);
  }
  /* Move front */
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(1px);
  }
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -7s;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3.5s;
}
/* This one is naturally at the front so we'll start with it */
.card:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card" style="background-color: red"></div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: blue"></div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: green"></div>
</div>
```

The percentages and time values are based on these calculations:

```
at front: 0s - start point 1
hold front: 3s (3 / 10.5 = 28.57%)
move left: 0.5s (3.5 / 10.5 = 33.33%)  - start point 2
hold left: 3s (6.5 / 10.5 = 61.90%)
move right: 0.5s (7 / 10.5 = 66.67%) - start point 3
hold right: 3s (10 / 10.5 = 95.23%)
move front: 0.5s (10.5 / 10.5 = 100%)
```

If you want to adjust any timings you'll need to recalculate using the same method.

Answer (score -1):

I think this page will help you : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

You can do a transition with each card moving, fading to opacity: 0 & doing illusion it passed under the other card.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).